# Getting IMEI number using ADB commands Android 12

Tags: android, adb, android-debug, android-12, getproperties

For android versions before 11 I was using the below command to get IMEI number from my device:

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 4 | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

or

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | toybox cut -d "'" -f2 | toybox grep -Eo '[0-9]' | toybox xargs | toybox sed 's/\ //g'
```

From android 12 it's not working anymore, these returns nothing

Can someone help with it ?

Comment: This affects me as well.  Looking for information on this.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what's working on my device on Android 12:

```sh
adb root
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 i64 0 | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

- The IMEI is accessible via root only
- It wants an extra 64-bit integer to be sent to the service.

`iphonesubinfo` calls change somewhat with every Android version. I didn't check the implementations, so the code above is just result of experimenting with the service. `iphonesubinfo 1` seems to report the IMEI on previous Android version as well though, at least from Android 10 on.