# How to get IMEI using adb command on Android 13?

Tags: android, shell, adb, imei, android-13

There is a question about [Getting IMEI number using ADB commands Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022247/getting-imei-number-using-adb-commands-android-12).

```
adb root
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 i64 0 | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

I tested the method, and it works well on Android 12.

But from android 13 on, it just returns an error message: "Package does not belong to ..."

Does anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 s16 com.android.shell | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

Here is what you want

Comment: Great job! But how did you find the command? Is there any trick?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Below ADB command uses UIAutomator of Android.

*Method*: *Call app* -> **#06# -> Get value*

```
adb shell "imei=$(input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP;input keyevent KEYCODE_CALL;sleep 1;input text '*#06#'; uiautomator dump --compressed /dev/stdout|sed s/\>\<\/\\n/g|grep -A1 IMEI1|tail -n1|sed -e 's/.*text=\"//' -e 's/\".*//'); echo ${imei:0:16}"
```

You can edit to get IMEI1, IMEI2, SN. My phone is Samsung Galaxy, if you use other phone brands, edit it accordingly.

*Note: Not work when your phone is locked*

Comment: It produces some privilege exceptions like "Exception occurred while executing 'keyevent':
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting input events requires the caller (or the source of the instrumentation, if any) to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission."